# cURL Error : The cookie file could not be opened

Tags: php, apache, curl, cookies

I am using AdobeHDS PHP script from here https://github.com/K-S-V/Scripts/wiki

This script is executed through another PHP script using `system()` function. But, on my web browser, I am getting the following error:

```
KSV Adobe HDS Downloader cURL Error : The cookie file could not be opened. Make sure this directory has the correct permissions. 1
```

The code I am using to execute this script is:

```
system ( '/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/inc/AdobeHDS.php --manifest someFile --delete --outfile someFile --outdir someDir' );
```

Is there something related to apache file/folder permissions?

Comment: As this error is stating, the webserver executing the script doesn't have the permission to open the file (user is www-data).

Comment: This script is in inc folder. I have already done chown -R www-data:www-data inc. Anything else I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made Apache the owner of inc directory where the AdobeHDS script is present. Problem solved.